# Find the remainder of $\frac{1! +2!+\, \dots\, +95! }{15}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think I found my answer but I am looking for better ones

Comment: [A note for reviewers: Arnab has provided an answer below.]

Comment: Hint: $\,\ 5\cdot 3\mid 5!\mid 6!\!\mid 7!\mid \dots\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each member of the sum that includes both 3 and 5 is divisible by 15. So all members of the sum other than $1!$, $2!$, $3!$, and $4!$ are divisible by 15, and we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{95} i! \equiv 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! \equiv 33 \equiv 3 \textrm{ (mod } 15)$$

Answer (score 5):

LHN = 1 + 2 + (2.3) + ................................ + (2.3.4.....95)
    = 1 + 2 + (2.3) + (2.3.4) + (2.3.4.5) + .........+ (2.3.4.....95)
    = 1 + 2 + (6) + (24) + (15.8) +...............+ (2.3.4.....95)
    = ( 1 + 2 +   6    +   24  ) + (15.8) + (15.48)+............+ (2.3.4.....95)

So,
   LHN modulo 15
 =  { (33) + (15.8) + (15.8.6)+............+ (2.3.4.....95) } modulo 15
=  (33 modulo 15 ) + {  15(8 + 8.6 + 8.6.7 + 8.6.7.8 + .........+ (8.6.7.8....95) } modulo  15
 = (33 % 15 ) + { 15 x SOMETHING } % 15
 = 3 + 0 = 3

Comment: Your answer needs no improvement, except perhaps in notation. Note that if $k\ge 5$ then $k!\equiv 0\pmod{15}$. So your expression is congruent to $1!+2!+3!+4!$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** There is no remainder from the terms from $5!$ to $95!$ inclusive (why?)

Comment: The OP has already demonstrated this in their answer.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Oh yes I see but didn't know that that was the OP when I wrote this.